# Accessing individual bytes in an array

Tags: arrays, pointers, byte

I'm trying to access individual bytes of a wide-char array so that I can send it via winsock, and this is what I've got so far:

```
WCHAR* buffer_in_bytes = (WCHAR*)msc->wcArray;
unsigned char l;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i <= (msc->bSize*2); i++ )
{
    l = (unsigned char)(*(buffer_in_bytes +i));
    char s[256] ;
    _itoa(l,s,16);
    OutputDebugString(s);
}
```

They array contains a series of a(s) (aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa....), and I would expect to see `00 61 00 61 00 61`  as a result I get `61 61 61 61 61 61`

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each element contains an 'a', or ASCII 61, which is what you see printed.  I don't know why you would expect to see these interspersed with 0's.

Comment: It's a wchar array so each character takes up two bytes, in fact looking at the array in memory view it shows up as (61 00 61 00 61 00 61 00 ..)

Comment: But you're reading out each array element, regardless of its size.  Maybe if you cast it as an array of 1-byte items...